# Invalid Binaries in iTunes Connect - The value for the key 'CFBundleExecutable' in bundle (bundle_path) is invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm having trouble sending my app through iTunes Connect.
Once sent, it switched to invalid binary state. I received an e-mail showing the issue :

> Invalid Info.plist value - The value for the key 'CFBundleExecutable' in bundle Juste-à-Temps.app/PlugIns/Juste-à-Temps WatchKit Extension.appex is invalid. CFBundleExecutable must match the name of the bundle directory minus its extension.

Here's my Info.plist file CFBundle part :

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Juste-à-Temps WatchKit Extension</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.adriencanterot.Juste-a--Temps.watchkitextension</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>XPC!</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>10</string>
```

In the archive that I sent, I went to see to value of CFBundleExecutable and here it is :

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>Juste-à-Temps WatchKit Extension</string>
```

Which literally matches the bundle name minus the .appex extension.
I tried to set such name manually but it didn't work either.
Notice that I had submitted 4 builds up until now and that they passed every validation successfully.
I didn't modify my WatchKit Extension or WatchKit app in those builds as they were ready long before I submitted the first build.
What changed to me is that I updated Xcode last week to 6.3.2.

I really don't understand why
Thank you very much for your help,
I'll answer as quickly as possible if needed.

Comment: remove special characters from app name, i think its the issue

Comment: I guess the main app and watch kit app would suffer from the same issue. And I committed 4 builds already.
Yet I tried removing the accent, still not working, I'm having the same issue